# Как посчитать интервал между двумя сообщениями pycord

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py, discord, pycord

Делаю бота дс который будет выдавать опыт (систему опыта и бд уже сделал) за сообщение. Хочу сделать проверку чтобы люди специально не спамили и не получали опыт, что я имею в виду:
Человек отправляет сообщение, ему выдали 10-50 опыта, а потом бот должен заснуть на 10сек(чтобы он не принимал сообщений), а потом проснуться и так циклично.

`asyncio.sleep(10)` и
`time.sleep(10)`
не помогают.
Использую:

***Pycord dev(pycord development)***

***Python3.11***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно просто запоминать дату и время (`datetime`) последнего сообщения от каждого пользователя и затем смотреть разницу во времени с новыми сообщениями, приходящими в обработчик `on_message`

Например, так:

```py
from datetime import datetime
import discord

bot = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.all())

user_last_message_dict = {}

@bot.event
async def on_message(message: discord.Message):
    # если даты последнего сообщения от такого пользователя еще нет, то добавляем
    if message.author.id not in user_last_message_dict:
        user_last_message_dict[message.author.id] = datetime.now()

    # если с последнего сообщения от пользователя прошло 10 секунд
    if (datetime.now() - user_last_message_dict[message.author.id]).seconds >= 10:
        . . . # здесь выдача опыта и т.п.

    # запоминаем дату последнего сообщения от этого пользователя
    user_last_message_dict[message.author.id] = datetime.now()

bot.run(TOKEN)
```